# Parallel Hints in "Select Into" statement in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

Parallel hints in normal DML SQL queries in oracle can be used in following fashion

```
 select /*+ PARALLEL (A,2) */  * from table A ;
```

In similar fashion can we use parallel hints in PL/SQL for select into statements in oracle?

```
  select /*+ PARALLEL(A,2) */ A.* BULK COLLECT INTO g_table_a from Table A ;
```

If i use the above syntax is there any way to verify whether the above select statement is executed in parallel?

Edit : Assuming g_table_a is a table data structure of ROWTYPE table

Comment: It seems to me that the sort of data volumes that would benefit from parallel query would be too large to be held in memory. How many rows do you expect to retrieve, and how many rows are in the table from which you are selecting?

Comment: 5mil rows are expected to be retrieved total rows in the table is around 7 mil rows.

Comment: That does not seem to be a great many for parallel query, but it is a lot to be held in memory (depending on the row size of course). Is the end goal of this procedure to insert the rows elsewhere, or perhaps to modify them? If so, can you instead use a single SQL statement? That would be the best first attempt at improving performance.

Comment: Yes the end goal is to modify the rows returned. will try to modify them into a singlle SQL statement.

Comment: Good plan – that is definitely the way towards a high performance system. SQL first!

Answer (score 2):

If the statement takes short elapsed time, you **don't want to run it in parallel**. Note, that e.g. query taking say 0.5 seconds in serial execution could take 2,5 second in parallel, as the most overhead is to set up the parallel execution.

So, if the query takes long time, you have enough time to check `V$SESSION` (use `gv$session`in RAC) and see all session with the user running the query.

```
select * from gv$session where username = 'your_user'
```

For serial execution you see only one session, for parallel execution you see one coordinator and additional session up to twice of the chosen parallel degree.

Alternative use the `v$px_session` which connects the *parallel worker sessions* with the query coordinator.

```
 select SID, SERIAL#, DEGREE, REQ_DEGREE 
 from v$px_session 
 where  qcsid = <SID of the session running teh parallel statement>;
```

Here you see also the *required degree of parallelism* and the real used *DOP*

Answer (score 0):

YOu can easily check this from Explain Plan of the query. In case of Plsql you can also have trace of the procedure and check in the TKprof file.